# 401 Unauthorized with Wordpress Basic Auth Plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api, wordpress-json-api, wordpress-admin

I have installed the plugin made by the Wordpress Team:
https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth

I am making this request with Wordpress 4.9.4:

```
GET http://somehostname.com/index.php?rest_route=%2Fwp%2Fv2%2Fposts&per_page=100&page=2&context=edit HTTP/1.1
Host: somehostname.com
Authorization: Basic [****base64encoded username+":"+pass *******]
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: [some user agent name]
```

Response:

```
HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
Date: Tue, 13 Feb 2018 14:26:12 GMT
Server: Apache
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.1.12
X-Robots-Tag: noindex
Link: <http://somehostname.com/wp-json/>; rel="https://api.w.org/"
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: X-WP-Total, X-WP-TotalPages
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Content-Type
Vary: Accept-Encoding,User-Agent
Content-Length: 127
Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8

{"code":"rest_forbidden_context","message":"Sorry, you are not allowed to edit posts in this post type.","data":{"status":401}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this fixed just now by doing as this comment is suggesting:
[Fix for basic OAuth](https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth/issues/35#issuecomment-244001216)
Not sure if this fix has any side effects though?

Answer (score 1):

Please add the following code on your `htaccess` file.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
```

and if you logged in as a wordpress admin right now than it will not allow you to create a post so first logout from wordpress admin and than try to make a request.

These two solutions had solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm inferring from your question that this is not supposed to be happening. You're expecting some response code that is not of the `4xx` variety.

From the title: "401 Unauthorized with Wordpress Basic Auth Plugin", I'm also making a leap, but it's possible that you're thinking that the plugin is not allowing you to access that route in *any* sense.

So, with that in mind, I'd like to point out that the error data is telling you something pretty precise: that *user* isn't allowed to edit posts of that type. That's **not** the same as that *user*'s credentials are invalid.

```
{
    "code": "rest_forbidden_context",
    "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to edit posts in this post type.",
    "data": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

Try confirming that the user whose credentials you're supplying in the `[****base64encoded username+":"+pass *******]` format is an admin/author/editor (or other role) that has permission to edit posts of the type you're trying to access.

Edit: See [this line](https://github.com/WP-API/WP-API/blob/d4011e786139c8a7558d096e41e140702e502ff9/lib/endpoints/class-wp-rest-posts-controller.php#L88) of the WP-API, where that error is likely originating

Comment: thank you for the quick reply.

The user I have tested with is an Admin, which has all the possible capabilities ON. I checked with the User Role Plugin and that Admin has all the possible capabilities that exist.

Comment: Try `var_dump`ing the `$user` variable here and confirm it's indeed admin: https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth/blob/master/basic-auth.php#L38 Further – confirm admin can modify the resource you're after!

Comment: So, the control does not go to line 38 at all.
It returns here:
https://github.com/WP-API/Basic-Auth/blob/master/basic-auth.php#L23

Comment: And the var_dump of $user at line 23 is bool(false)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the auth issue by following this very brief advice

https://github.com/WordPress/application-passwords/wiki/Basic-Authorization-Header----Missing

I also had to move the wordpress block up to the top of the htaccess

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by the following steps:

1. Verify, if the `password protected` plugin installed, then
2. Goto Password protected plugin's settings
3. Check *'Allow REST API Access'*
4. Save Changes

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can add this snippet in .htaccess to solve this error

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=REMOTE_USER:%{HTTPS:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```